# Vector and matrices question (Introduction to finite mathematics 3rd edition)

Tags: matrices

Stuck on this exercise for quite a while now;
(u1+u2+u3+u4) multiplied by the matrix \begin{pmatrix}
u1\\
u2\\ 
u3\\ 
u4
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
3\\ 
5\\ 
7
\end{pmatrix}

Find u1,u2,u3,u4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mathematica, this can be solved via

```
Solve[(u1 + u2 + u3 + u4) u1 == 1 && (u1 + u2 + u3 + u4) u2 == 
   3 && (u1 + u2 + u3 + u4) u3 == 5 && (u1 + u2 + u3 + u4) u4 == 
   7, {u1, u2, u3, u4}]
```

which yields two solutions:

$$\left\{\left\{\text{u1}\to -\frac{1}{4},\text{u2}\to -\frac{3}{4},\text{u3}\to
   -\frac{5}{4},\text{u4}\to -\frac{7}{4}\right\},\left\{\text{u1}\to
   \frac{1}{4},\text{u2}\to \frac{3}{4},\text{u3}\to \frac{5}{4},\text{u4}\to
   \frac{7}{4}\right\}\right\}$$